# not able to convert double value to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I was trying to convert `double` value to 2 decimal places, by using below two methods.

**DecimalFormat**

```
double value = 2.384185791015625E-4;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

**Math.round**

```
double value = 2.384185791015625E-4;
double newValue = Math.round(value*100.0)/100.0;
System.out.println(newValue);
```

in both cases I am getting `0` output. I was expecting output to be `2.38`.
can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: `I was expecting output to be 2.38` Your number is `0.0002384185791015625` though, so rounding to two decimal places leaves `0.00`.

Comment: What do you think `E-4` suffix mean? Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation

Comment: @tkausl can you please tell me, how you have convert 2.384185791015625E-4 to 0.0002384185791015625..this can solve my problem.

Comment: It already has that value , there is no need to convert it

Comment: `x E-4` is a way of saying its `x * 10^(-4)`. Which means it's the `x` but shifted `4` times to the right. So if we would have `2.5E-4` the value is `0.00025`. Especially when having small values like `0.0000000025` the value is easier to read and understand if you write `2.5E-9` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get 2.38 since the value of the double is `0.0002384185791015625`
and since you are rounding off to two decimal places you will get `0.00`

Comment: When you downvote, adding a comment will make it clear why the downvote was done